# Copy/paste Arabic doesn't work well

Tags: arabic

On http://tanzil.net/#19:3, if you copy the first word of the first line to the right including the "(1)" and then paste it in the WordPress editor, you'll see that the "(1)" piece is split (left parenthesis moves to the beginning of the sentence for some reason). This occurs either on computers with Arabic language installed and those without.

Why and how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Probably because the reading order is set to **Left to Right** by default.

**Before**

[image: Before]

Right-click and select **Right to left Reading order**:

[image: RTL]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karan, it works indeed. However my real problem is that I need to use this in WordPress. I don't know why I mentioned Notepad, sorry. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @drake035: Have you checked whether the WP editor has that RtL option anywhere? Also, if it is a web-based app, in Firefox at least you can press Ctrl+Shift+X to toggle between LtR and RtL.

Comment: There's such option for WP in Arabic only. Nevermind, I applied a CSS direction: rtl

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this :

1. Copy and paste the arabic text into from word or text document to ADOBE Illustrator.
2. Save the illustrator document as in .EPS format.
3. Open indesign and place the .EPS document into the place you want.

Since indesign can't handle arabic text issue by itself, this method will help many designers.